# How can i redirect my site?

Tags: url, redirect

My url like this `directoryname.abc.com` and i want to redirect my url look like as  `www.abc.com` so please help me for this.I want to just remove directory name above url name.

Comment: Change the directory your domain points to?

Comment: You can redirect through your site's cPanel.

Comment: You can make a DNS Permanent redirection. Take a [look here](http://www.ovh.com/fr/domaines/).

Answer (score 0):

For most hosting providers content in `public_html` or `htdocs` folder shows at root domain. So try looking for any of these folders and move your site content to it.

Domains like 'abc.com' are purchased for domain sellers. If you have purchased a domain then your seller must have provided a control panel. Tell which control panel you have for more specific solution.

If you are using some free service like blogspot, wordpress.com, wix.com or webs.com etc. Then you need to purchase a domain.

If you want to redirect to another page, you can use:

**JavaScript**

```
<script>window.location = "http://example.com";</script>
```

**html**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

**PHP**

```
<?php header('Locaction: http://example.com'); ?>
```